# Finding a minimum cut with an upper bound on the set sizes

Tags: graphs, reference-request, minimum-cuts

In the (unweighted) [minimum k-cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut), the goal is to partition the nodes in a given graph to at least $k$ subsets, such that the number of edges between different subsets is as small as possible.

I am interested in a variant in which the number of subsets is not fixed in advance, but there can be at most $t$ vertices in each subset. So the goal is to partition the nodes into subsets of cardinality at most $t$, such that the number of edges between different subsets is as small as possible.

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem, assuming $t$ is fixed? And assuming $t$ is part of the input?

Comment: Might be helpful to look at: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/HR73.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is called Component Order edge-Connectivity.  The *edge* here refers to deletion of edges.  See e.g. [Gross et al.](http://combinatorialmath.com/index.php/ArsCombinatoria/article/view/2146).

The problem is defined as follows.  Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ and two integers $k$ and $\ell$, is it possible to delete at most $k$ edges from $G$ such that in the resulting graph, each connected component has at most $\ell$ vertices.

The problem is related to the vulnerability measure *Edge Integrity*, where you minimize the sum of the largest connected component and the size of the cuts.  See e.g. the survey by [Bagga et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X94900841).